# Why do I get "error ReferenceError: document is not defined" with Nextjs when using Base Web?

Tags: javascript, next.js, baseweb, styletron

I see a couple of answers here on `error ReferenceError: document is not defined` but none of the solutions work for my particular case. Previously marked as duplicate but isn't the solution and the post is 3 years 9 months out of date and the syntax is much different now for both React and Next and SSR vs Client Rendering.

In the terminal it reads:

```
- error node_modules/styletron-engine-atomic/dist-node-cjs/client/client.js (167:0) @ new StyletronClient
- error ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at eval (./src/app/layout.js:15:16)
    at (sc_client)/./src/app/layout.js (/Users/anthonyweston/Sites/fogg/.next/server/app/page.js:2296:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/me/Sites/nextjs-baseweb/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
null
```

I see some references to next/dynamic mentioned in other questions, but that doesn't seem to be the solution here?

The package is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/anthonysw3/nextjs-baseweb) if you want to reproduce.

Comment: Review if the styletron lib works in the server.

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. How might I do that? I am using `"use client"` on each of the pages and components, but I still get the `ReferenceError`